# python GET requests error 422. Key format is not valid

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I need to update python script to work with additional data which are not there at the moment. Hence the use of "requests" but somehow it's not working for me.

**Basically I need python version of below curl which is providing data I need e.g.:**

*curl -X GET -H "Authorization: GenieKey XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 'https://api.eu.opsgenie.com/v2/alerts/f013a45e-4227-44bb-a0a7-9b2cb6c7c2d9-1616676741714?identifierType=id'*

```json
{
   "data":{
      "seen":true,
      "id":"f013a45e-4227-44bb-a0a7-9b2cb6c7c2d9-1616676741714",
      "tinyId":"400",
      "alias":"test MP",
      "message":"MP testing",
      "status":"open",
      "acknowledged":true,
      "isSeen":true,
      "tags":[
         "MP testing",
         "sre"
      ],
      "snoozed":false,
      "count":1,
      "lastOccurredAt":"2021-03-25T12:52:21.714Z",
      "createdAt":"2021-03-25T12:52:21.714Z",
      "updatedAt":"2021-04-16T10:28:18.372Z",
      "source":"mail@mail.no",
      "owner":"mail@mail.no",
      "priority":"P5",
      "teams":[
         {
            "id":"45c719c5-d3e1-4e75-9284-b0c75103d44a"
         }
      ],
      "responders":[
         {
            "type":"team",
            "id":"45c719c5-d3e1-4e75-9284-b0c75103d44a"
         }
      ],
      "integration":{
         "id":"132f80a5-b653-4b8a-ba33-eed59cfd6a0a",
         "name":"Default API",
         "type":"API"
      },
      "report":{
         "ackTime":1892156658,
         "acknowledgedBy":"mail@mail.no"
      },
      "ownerTeamId":"45c719c5-d3e1-4e75-9284-b0c75103d44a",
      "actions":[
         
      ],
      "entity":"TEST MP",
      "description":"popis problemu {{priority}}",
      "details":{
         "priority2":"jednicka",
         "issueKey":"FIXIT-981939"
      }
   },
   "took":0.005,
   "requestId":"b1f0f485-b06e-45f2-88c0-fe5809cd1ea9"
}
```

**Part of the python script I need to create looks like this for now:**

```py
import requests

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://api.eu.opsgenie.com/v2/alerts/f013a45e-4227-44bb-a0a7-9b2cb6c7c2d9-1616676741714?identifierType=id', auth=('Correct ID', 'Correct PW'))

print(response.text)              # To print unicode response string
print(response)
```

**Result I am getting:**

root@server: pts/0: 2 files -> python3 get_request2.py

```
<Response [422]>
```

```json
{
   "message":"Key format is not valid!",
   "took":0.001,
   "requestId":"cc21637d-c864-4ba0-92a6-e454ddb74663"
}
```

Can you please help to determine why I am not getting the data as it is working from shell via curl? I tried to find similar topics but no solution for working for me. I tried add headers or verify=False but no success. Sensitive info is hidden.
Source data are in JSON if it matters and python version is 3.4.10
Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: Use `headers={'Authorization': 'GenieKey XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')` instead of `auth=…`.

Comment: It works! Thanks Klaus D. You helped a lot